Проблема с репозитарием в DNF
После вчерашнего обновления fedora до версии 41 вдруг перестала работать утилита dnf. Если пытаюсь её запустить, то выдаётся сообщение:

Недопустимый идентификатор репозитория "Flatpak Repo": неожиданный
символ ' '

Оно и раньше выдавалось, но раньше утилита просто шла дальше и можно было не обращать внимание на этот репозитарий злосчастный. Но теперь утилита просто падает и сделать ничего не могу. Даже распечатать список репозитариев не могу:
$ dnf repolist all
Недопустимый идентификатор репозитория "Flatpak Repo": неожиданный символ ' '

Не могу даже вспомнить, где расположен список репозитариев, что бы в ручную его поправить.
Кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой ?

Разобрался сам:

Список репозитариев находится в /etc/yum.repos.d/
Битым был репозитарий Flathub

